# React.Fragment only works with import React (not with import { React })

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For some reason if I try and use <React.Fragment> with

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
```

at the top of my page I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Fragment')
```

If I switch this to

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
```

it works just fine. Is this indicative of a problem somewhere else?

Comment: [Please read about exports here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) ... so you can understand that `React` is exported as `default` ...

Comment: I understand the difference, but nowhere in there does it not say you can't import a default using { Default } and in the react starter docs they mention react can be imported as { React } or React. Are you saying you can have

`export default React`
and
`export React`
In one file and have them be two separate objects? i.e. `export React` in this case being a subset of `export default React`

Comment: It's react code that they default React export ... can you link docs that says we can export either way ?

Comment: To be honest @KcH I can't find it. Must of just confused myself!

Answer (score 2):

{ React } is worng usage. 
If you use typescript the error will be shown right away.
[TS Error](https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS2595) check this link to see the exact error you are facing and its solution.

Comment: Yea I see that now, for some reason I just thought I had read somewhere that default exports get imported properly with { Default } the same as import Default